# Angular gives different results for the same call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using angular with ionic and it's acting in a very bizarre fashion.

```
var loco =  UserService.doesOrderExist();
  if (UserService.doesOrderExist()) {
    if(UserService.orderSize() > 0){
      return 'ion-bag';
    }else{
      return '';
    }
  } else if (CartService.numItems() > 0) {
    return 'ion-ios7-cart';
  }
```

Angular calls this piece of code several times. And returns "ion-bag".
Then suddenly it goes into the else case (during the same execution).

```
doesOrderExist: function() {
      return (me && me.current_order);
},
orderSize: function() {
      return me.current_order.length;
},
```

When I step into orderSize "me" becomes undefined after a certain number of calls.
I tried a different approach:

```
var loco =  UserService.doesOrderExist();
  if (loco || loco.length > 0) {
    return 'ion-bag';
  } else if (CartService.numItems() > 0) {
    return 'ion-ios7-cart';
  }
```

But despite being true every time it doesn't change the outcome probably because the Error:

> error:interr Interpolation Error Can't interpolate: button
>   button-ic…()}} TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null.

I'm just not sure what's going because if I only call doesOrderExist "me" is always defined if I separate into to separate evaluations then "me" becomes undefined after a few loops of being called by Angular/Ionic.
Any hints or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this problem is that js is dynamically typed and the code which I took over sometimes treats current_order as a boolean and at other times as an array.